# Custom fonts are not appearing after the build in Angular 4

Tags: angular, fonts

I am using my custom font files in Angular application. It was working fine with angular 2. I have upgraded to Angular 4 recently. Now the problem that I am facing is whenever I am updating the font files. The updated font doesn't appear after the build. What could be the possible reason for this?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "bm-dashboard-font";
  src:url("../../../assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.eot");
  src:url("../../../assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("../../../assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../../../assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../../../assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.svg#bm-dashboard-font") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}
```

Edit: I am using AOT

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: No, I am not using cli

Answer (score 0):

Please use **absolute** path instead of **relative**.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "bm-dashboard-font";
   src:url("/assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.eot");
   src:url("/assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
   url("/assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.woff") format("woff"),
   url("/assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.ttf") format("truetype"),
   url("/assets/fonts/bm-dashboard-font.svg#bm-dashboard-font") format("svg");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```